# += vs =+ in Java

Tags: java, programming-languages, operators

I am familiar with the += operator in java, that if executed like:

`i += 2;`

is the same as:

`i = i + 2;`

But what exactly is =+? It compiles fine in Java, but as far as I can tell it only assigns the result right-hand-side expression to the left-hand-side variable. i.e.

`i =+ 2`

is the same as:

`i = 2`

Anyone know what exactly is going on here? Apologies if this has been asked, the SEO for any question regarding operators is always wonky... Thanks!

Comment: It's `i =                +2` :D

Comment: `+` is not operator here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`i =+ 2` is the same as

```
i = +2;
```

i.e., the `+` is the unary `+` operator.

Answer (score 3):

`i =+ 2` is equivalent to `i = +2` where `+` is the [unary plus operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

Comment: That tutorial says that unary `+` “indicates positive value”. But that's not really true, you can do e.g. `+(-42)` or `+i` when `i` is negative.